# Format-number from ###.0 to ###.00

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I working with a project in BizTalk where use xslt to convert from and edifact file to an UBL file.
The edifact file contains price values of ###.0 and that do not work. I want to change it to ###.00 using format-number. But I cannot make it work.

This is what I have made so far:

```
<cbc:Value>
    <xsl:variable name="SumOfNodes" select="edi:PRI/edi:C509/C50902"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($SumOfNodes, '0.00')"/>
</cbc:Value>
```

I am using this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:edi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006/MEDIAMARKT"
                xmlns:ubl="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2"
                xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
                xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl edi">
```

Any ideas on how to solve this??

Comment: What is this giving you?

Comment: Error: 2 (Field level error)
 SegmentID: PRI
 Position in TS: 87
 Data Element ID: C50902
 Position in Segment: 2
 Position in Field: 2
 Data Value: 86.0
 37: Invalid character(s) found in data element

Comment: So what data is in that segment?

Comment: Your error message suggests the actual value is `86.0 37`. Have you checked the source document?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file please, this would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to undeclared namespace in your XSLT. Please check whether namespaces are declared correctly in your XSLT. Unless you show the full XSLT coding with XML coding, we cannot able to provide solution. However please refer the below Sample XML and XSLT with the output

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="chapter">
<Value>
    <xsl:variable name="num" select="number"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($num,'00.00')"/>
</Value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<chapter>
<number>45</number>
</chapter>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Value>45.00</Value>
```